# How should I set up my sub-domain to allow it listen on a port for web socket transfer?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, web-server, port, websocket

This may be a really beginner question, but I really want to make sure I'm going in the right direction before investing time in this. Heres what I have.

**charlieli.me @ 45.55.33.185:80**

**fileserver.charlieli.me @ 45.55.33.185:80**

*fileserver.conf*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName fileserver.charlieli.me
    ServerAdmin charlie.li@carleton.ca
    ServerAlias fileserver.charlieli.me
    DocumentRoot /var/www/fileserver
    <Directory /var/www/fileserver>
        # enable the .htaccess rewrites
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted

    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_orlybg.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_orlybg.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

My primary domain's virtual host is 45.55.33.185 port 80, my subdomain fileserver.charlieli.me is also configured to 45.55.33.185 port 80.

On my subdomain, I would like to open a web-socket to send files to store and retrieve remotely. In my configuration for the landing site, it's configured to port 80, does this mean I have to listen/receive/respond through port 80 or could I specify another port on the subdomain like 9090 top open with my websocket program and receive data from fileserver.charlieli.me:9090?

Does the "Virtual Host" address in my conf really mean both my primary and subdomain is really sharing the same set of ports and I can access my 9090 port even from charlieli.me:9090 rendering a subdomain redundant?